Is optuna's XGBoostPruningCallback working?
I'm having trouble getting the XGBoostPruningCallback to work. Every attempt leads to the error 'callback must be an instance of TrainingCallback.' Someone in a GitHub thread claims this is a compatibility issue with version 2.0 of XGBoost.
In the same thread, it is said that a solution is to install the development version of Optuna:
pip install git+https://github.com/optuna/optuna.git


However, this doesn't seem to work anymore.
This is my piece of code, so you can replicate the error.
def objective(trial):

    train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, stratify=bins)
    dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(train_x, label=train_y)
    dtest = xgb.DMatrix(test_x, label=test_y)


    param = {
        'lambda': trial.suggest_loguniform('lambda', 1e-3, 10.0),
        'alpha': trial.suggest_loguniform('alpha', 1e-3, 10.0),
        'colsample_bytree': trial.suggest_categorical('colsample_bytree', [0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9, 1.0]),
        'subsample': trial.suggest_categorical('subsample', [0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,1.0]),
        'learning_rate': trial.suggest_loguniform('learning_rate', 0.01, 1.0),
        'n_estimators': trial.suggest_int('n_estimators', 1000, 5000), 
        'max_depth': trial.suggest_categorical('max_depth', [5,7,9,11,13,15,17]),
        'min_child_weight': trial.suggest_int('min_child_weight', 1, 300),
    }

    param.update(common_params)

    # model = xgb(**param)  

    pruning_callback = optuna.integration.XGBoostPruningCallback(trial, "validation-rmsle")
    
    model = xgb.train(param, dtrain, evals=[(dtest, "validation")], early_stopping_rounds=100, callbacks=[pruning_callback])
    
    preds = model.predict(test_x)
    
    score = rmsle(test_y, preds)
    
    return score

study = optuna.create_study(direction='minimize')
study.optimize(objective, n_trials=30)
print('Number of finished trials:', len(study.trials))
print('Best trial:', study.best_trial.params)



Could you share the executable script? The current one does not have import and definition of dataset.
